# Formality of Treating Differential Operators as a Variable in Solving Diff Eqs.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is these methods in an Engineering Book of an Indian author where the particular solution of a linear Differential Equations of higher order are treated using differential operator $D$.

Now, the author justified that in the case where the diff eq. are :
$(D^3 - 3D + 2)y = e^x$

For the particular soln simply put:
$y = \frac{e^x}{D³-3D+2}$ where $D=1$

Clearly the denominator will become zero so the author stated another method in that particular case:

Differentiate the denominator with respect to D and multiply the numerator by $x$

$y= x\frac{e^x}{d\frac{(D³-3D+2)}{dD}} $ where $D=1$

So by induction the general formula
for finding the particular soln of that forcing function becomes:

$y = x^n\frac{e^{ax}}{\frac{d^nf(D)}{dD}}$ where $D=a$ until the numerator is not 0 upon substitution

My question is, why is this valid?

Similarly for the particular soln for linear Differential Equation of the forcing function $x^n$

Simply use the negative Binomial Theorem for the $f(D)$:

Ex. $(D^2+D)y = x^2$
Put $y = (D^2+D)^{-1}(x^2)$
By separating $\frac{1}{D}$ and from the binomial Theorem:

$y = \frac{1}{D}(1-D+D^2....)(x^2)$

For $D^n$ and $n > 2 $ the $ x^2$ becomes 0 and the ​answer becomes:

$y = \frac{x²-2x+2}{D}$ and operate by $\frac{1}{D}$

Why is Differential Operators allowed to be treated in these way?
Also, what particular subject or topic can I read to understand things like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: Why is Differential Operators allowed to be treated in these way? Also, what particular subject or topic can I read to understand things like these?

Answer:

Your question is like asking about fourier or Laplace transform. Let me discuss using Laplace transform:
Define $L(f(x)) = \int f(x) e^{-sx} dt$. It turns out u can recover $f(x)$ from $L(f(x))$. 
Let Laplace transform of $y=f(x)$ be written as $L(y)$.  
A Property of $L$: $L(\frac{dy}{dx}) = sL(y)$ 
Hence the Differential equation can be written as $P(s) L(y) = L(e^x)$ where $P(s)$ is a polynomial in $s$.
Hence $y = L^{-1}(\frac{L(e^x)}{P(s)})$.

Another Property of $L$:
$L^{-1} (Y_1(s) Y_2(s)) = L^{-1}(Y_1(s)) * L^{-1}(Y_2(s))$ where $*$ is convolution.

We have : $y = e^x * L^{-1}(\frac{1}{P(s)})$. 
Let $L^{-1}(\frac{1}{P(s)})=p_1(x)$ 
$y = e^x * p_1 =\int e^{(x-t)} p_1(t) dt = e^x L(p_1)|_{s=1} = e^x (1/(P(s))|_{s=1}$.

This is exactly what the book suggests. You can see that the idea works only if the right hand side is $e^x$.

Hope its clear.

Now coming to ur first question.
let $L^{-1}(P(s)) = p(x)$. 
We need $\frac{1}{x}\frac{dP(s)}{ds} = \frac{1}{x} \int \frac{d(p(x)e^{-sx})}{ds} dx =  -\int p(x)e^{sx} dx  = -P(s)$

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite follow. I can't connect the method of Laplace Transform in the formality behind differentiating a Differential Operator with respect to D itself. The laplace transform allows such operations because by definition, it is a premultipled integral.

Comment: Meanwhile, the Differential Operator D is simply d/dx and I can't formally connect how it is plausible to differentiate it with respect to D example - d(D)/dD = 1, even worse, using the negative exponent binomial theorem on D

Comment: @mkcpz Hi dont think $D$ as differential operator but rather as the variable $s$ in Laplace transform. If u do this then everything will fall into place.

Comment: @mkcpz solve by taking Laplace transform and compare it with what we do with $D$, it will be same. People dont state this explicitly.

Comment: Ok thank you very much